# Cloudfront is delivering the contents of my S3 bucket with the wrong MIME types

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a static site in an S3 bucket behind a Cloudfront dist and a Lambda Edge function, and both the JS and CSS files in the bucket are being delivered as html/text, even though in the S3 console they have the correct MIME types set in the S3 console metadata. I triggered an invalidation in case there was a cache issue, but no luck. Why is this happening?

Comment: What do you see in content-type metadata field in S3 for the objects? Cloudfront doesn't modify the content-type it will server as what the origin has defined.